# Running emacs in graphics mode on remote server

Tags: linux, emacs, ssh, x11-forwarding

Basically I am using emacs on remote server (my school) but when I logged in to from linux and typed `emacs`, I got a text mode (terminal mode). Is there a way to launch emacs in graphics mode from remote server?

Comment: Are you using ssh between your local linux box and the remote machine? If the remote machine is linux, does its sshd have X11 forwarding enabled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **SSH X11 forwarding** to display the window *locally* but have it run on a *remote* machine.

There are many tutorials available and the configuration, while often not complicated, varies based on your operating system and such, and so I would recommend you simply Google the phrase "ssh x11 forwarding" to learn more about setting it up.

SSH X11 forwarding uses the ssh connection between your computer and the server you're connecting to, in order to tunnel the communication protocol graphic programs use. This usually means that in order to connect to the server, instead of running `ssh <servername>` you run `ssh -X <servername>`, and if your server is configured properly, you can then simply run remotely `emacs` or any other graphical program, and have it display on your local machine.

Comment: what is ssh x11 forwarding? could you please give me some more instructions?

Comment: Open a connection with `ssh -X` and your environment should be set properly for X11 forwarding.

Comment: @Mark, I've updated the answer with a little more information on the subject.

Comment: You probably also want to read what the ssh man page has to say about X11 security (search for `-X`).

Comment: Seems I have problems to judge the " if your server is configured properly," part in my case. Any tips?